# Trigonometry Identity: $\tan \theta\sin \theta + \cos \theta = \sec \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Sorry if my question seems too simple. I cannot find a proof and my text book does not provide one either. I am supposed to prove:

$$\tan \theta \times \sin \theta + \cos \theta = \sec \theta$$

I know that $\sec = \frac{1}{\cos\theta}$. But I do not know how to prove that $\tan \theta \times \sin \theta + \cos \theta = \frac{1}{\cos \theta}$.

I appreciate if someone point me to the right direction.

Comment: First write $\tan\theta\sin\theta+\cos\theta={\sin^2\theta\over\cos\theta}+{\cos^2\theta \over\cos\theta}$.

Comment: I would start by writing the whole equation out in terms of sine and cosine functions.

Comment: Use the identity $sin^2 x + cos^2 x =1$.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If it is, you should accept an answer or provide your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\tan \theta \sin \theta + \cos \theta & \stackrel{\text{def.}}= \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos \theta} + \cos \theta \\
& \stackrel{\text{Pythagoras}}= \frac{1-\cos^2 \theta}{\cos \theta} + \cos \theta \\
& = \frac1{\cos\theta} - \cos \theta + \cos \theta \\
& \stackrel{\text{def.}}= \sec\theta
\end{align*}$$
Where we use the definitions of $\tan \theta$ and $\sec\theta$ plus Pythagoras' theorem $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

To Prove :$$\tan \theta\sin \theta + \cos \theta = \sec \theta$$

L.H.S :

$\tan \theta\sin \theta + \cos \theta $
$\implies \large\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}\times{\sin \theta} + \cos \theta $

$\implies \large \frac{\sin^2 \theta +\cos^2 \theta}{\cos \theta} $
$\implies \large \frac{1}{\cos \theta} $

$\implies \large {\sec \theta} $

:)

Comment: $\sin \theta \times \sin \theta + cos \theta$ should be equal to $\sin^{2}\theta + \cos\theta$. Why you square $\cos \theta$ and wrote $\sin^{2}\theta + cos^{2} \theta$?

Comment: There is a $\cos \theta$ in Denominator, cross multiply with $\cos \theta$ gives you $cos^2 \theta$. Can you see it/

Answer (score 1):

AS mentioned in a comment above
$$
\tan \theta =\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}.
$$

then your L.H.S becomes

$$
\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}.\sin \theta + \cos \theta
$$

from this can you add the terms together? and use $\sin^2 \theta +\cos^2 \theta = 1$

Answer (score 1):

First note that
\[
\tan\theta =\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}
\]
\[
\sin^{2}\theta+\cos^{2}\theta=1
\]
\[
\frac{a}{b}\pm c=\frac{a\pm bc}{b}
\]
So then
\[
\tan\theta\sin\theta+\cos\theta= \frac{\sin^{2}\theta}{\cos\theta}+\cos\theta= \frac{\sin^{2}\theta+\cos^{2}\theta}{\cos\theta}=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}=\sec\theta
\]